# How to return Average number of rolls from a dice?

Tags: c#, random, average, dice

I need to display the average number of rolls needed to get a six, and the number of sixes that average was based.
The problem I am having I think is with this part of the code? So I want the average number of rolls which I think I have as the variable AVGroll. The number of sixes the average was base on should be the loopcount variable.

```
        AVGroll = AVGroll + loopcount;
        average = AVGroll / loopcount;
```

Tried to comment my code as best as possible to make it readable.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Collections;

        namespace CE0721a
        {
            class Tut4_7
            {
                public void run()
                {
        // Random number generator 
        Random rndm = new Random();

        //declaring number for Random Number Generator
        int number;

       // average number of runs
        int average;

        //declaring loopcount starts at 1
        int loopcount = 1;

        //Average roll starts at 0
        int AVGroll = 0;

        //Variable if it continues
        int progcontinue;

        //Start lable
        Start:
        do
        {
            number = rndm.Next(6) + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.ReadKey();

           if (number < 6)
            {
                loopcount++;
            }

        } while (number != 6);



        AVGroll = AVGroll + loopcount;
        average = AVGroll / loopcount;

        Console.WriteLine("The roll count is:");
        Console.WriteLine(loopcount);
        Console.WriteLine("average");
        Console.WriteLine(AVGroll);
        Console.WriteLine("press 1 to continue or 0 to exit");




        progcontinue = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

        if (progcontinue > 0)
        {

            loopcount = 1;
            goto Start;

        }
        else
        {


        }
    }
}
        }
```

Comment: Your variable names are hard to read, try to put a underscore or capitalize the second words, like `AVG_roll` or AvgRoll`.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with your program in particular?  Error message?  Not behaving correctly?  How would you expect it to behave if it isn't behaving correctly?  All things that should go in the question.  I recommend avoiding `goto`.  Make it a `while(progcontinue) { /* ... */ }` loop instead.

Comment: Have you considered that the average number of rolls may not be an integral value?

Comment: an average is the sum of an arrays parts divided by the number of parts, you are half way there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have posted what I tried and where I think I am stuggling

Comment: Also, to counteract some of what Omeid suggested:  Don't use underscores in the middle of variable names in C#.  Name local variables with names that start with lower case, like `averageRoll`.  Use full words, avoiding abbreviations when you can, unless they're very common (such as `ipAddress` or `somethingId`) - `rndm` is not a common abbreviation.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I dont know how to get the average number of rolls thats my problem. My code runs fine but its not doing what I think it should do

Comment: Why do you need to use `goto`?

Comment: @Alex: Can you give examples of what you think it should do, and what it is actually doing?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham [link](http://imgur.com/5aQxg)

I suppose I use goto because it works? Why shouldnt I use it ?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by your code but I think you are using the wrong variables to calculate the AvgRoll. the first run AVGroll will always be 1 example:

```
 AVGroll = AVGroll (0) + loopcount (5);
    average = AVGroll (5) / loopcount (5);
```

so it will be 1

I think you need to do something like this:

```
     int timesContinued = 1;
        //Start lable
                Start:
                do
                {
                    number = rndm.Ne

xt(6) + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(number);
                Console.ReadKey();

               if (number < 6)
                {
                    loopcount++;
                }

            } while (number != 6);



            AVGroll = AVGroll + loopcount;
            average = AVGroll / timesContinued;

            Console.WriteLine("The roll count is:");
            Console.WriteLine(loopcount);
            Console.WriteLine("average");
            Console.WriteLine(AVGroll);
            Console.WriteLine("press 1 to continue or 0 to exit");




            progcontinue = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

            if (progcontinue > 0)
            {
                loopcount = 1;
                timesContinued++;
                goto Start;

            }
```

this way you will devided the total times rolled by the number of times that you pressed continue which I hope is what you wanted.

Comment: I think this does calculate average of rolls to get the 6. It's still not good coding (but that's another problem of the original question).

Answer (score 1):

You divide by the wrong thing:

```
    AVGroll = AVGroll + loopcount;
    average = AVGroll / loopcount;
```

You want to average over the number of trials. One trial is you roll until you get 6.
Then based on `progcontinue` you do more trials.

Thus have an extra variable that counts trials and divide by that:

```
    int trial =  1;

    //...

    AVGroll = AVGroll + loopcount;
    average = AVGroll / trials;

    //...

    if (progcontinue > 0)
    {

        loopcount = 1;
        ++trials;
        goto Start;

    }
```

Also you need to print `average`, not AVGroll:

```
    Console.WriteLine("average");
    Console.WriteLine(AVGroll); //should be average
```

Comment: `loopcount` is already the number of trials...  Why he's adding it to the average is a good question, though.

Comment: no it's not. Read carefully: "What is the average number of roll needed to get 6". One trial is "you roll until you get 6, then record the number of rolls" - that's loopcount. At that point the average is loopcount / 1 (as there is one trial). But you can keep trying to get 6 and recording the number of rolls it takes. And the question is about the average.

Comment: this looks like the same solution as mine, so +1 ^^

Comment: So I tried your solution and this is what I got. I have shown what I think it should be in red.
[link](http://imgur.com/5aQxg)